# Rewriting subdomain to directory with web.config on Azure Web App

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to host all my subdomains in respective folders on my webserver meaning

```
https://foo.bar.com/index.html
```

is located at

```
https://bar.com/foo/index.html
```

by my current configuration the file cannot and should not be accessed via the  "original" link, though.

My current approach works, except with **urls, that point to a subdirectory without a filename in the path** - in that case the subdomain is re-included in the path of the **rewritten** url:

```
https://foo.bar.com/this/does/work.html
```

serves the file located at

```
https://bar.com/foo/this/does/work.html
```

while

```
https://foo.bar.com/this/does/not/work
```

is rewritten in the browser to

```
https://foo.bar.com/foo/this/does/not/work
```

which for obvious reasons results in a 404.

If you however enter the url with the issues **directly** in the browser

```
https://foo.bar.com/this/does/not/work
```

it works as expected.

I know I'm using the word "obviously" in a loose sense. Here's a quick demo:

https://egal.todoservice.app/

as you should see there, the link on the page to
https://egal.todoservice.app/sub/dir/

takes you to
https://egal.todoservice.app/egal/sub/dir/

but try to enter that link directly in your address bar and it works - it does for me at least, tested in Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

**UPDATE:** strangely, using the subdir link here on stackoverflow works as expected...

This is the part of my web.config that is responsible for the subdomain-rewrite

```
<rule name="Rewrite Subdomain To Directory" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.+)\.todoservice\.app$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

And here is my full web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
             <mimeMap fileExtension=".nupkg" mimeType="application/zip" />
         </staticContent>        
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite SMZC URL" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.sadmenszombieclub.com"  />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="smzc/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite imagiro URL" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.imagiro.net"  />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="imagiro/{R:0}" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Rewrite Subdomain To Directory" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.+)\.todoservice\.app$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:0}" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Rewrite root path to service Directory" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^todoservice\.app$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="service/{R:0}" />
                </rule>                
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The whole site is hosted as an Azure Web App.

Comment: `<action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:0}" />` should include the full domain name (and you also need to enable ARR proxy mode, https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/).

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying - the "real" domain name (ie. blabla.azurewebsites.com) should be there and that only works with the ARR installed... but can you enlighten my why my approach works when the requested document is given?

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact opposite of what is described in that article - serve content from that one domain "foobar.azurewebsites.com" to different domains and subdomains... I just can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: @LexLi I got it to work. Thank you. If you make your comment into an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from comment.

You are doing more than simple rewriting, but reverse proxying. Thus, a few changes are needed to be carried out,

1. In your action, instead of rewriting the actual path (`<action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:0}" />`), you should also append the full domain name to `url`. In that way IIS knows you want to set up a reverse proxy.
2. Enable ARR proxy mode in Azure App Service by following blog posts such as https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/

Comment: I followed part of the blog post to make it work. Without the proxy rewrite to the "original" domain does not work. I'm pretty confident {<proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" />} was the only line i needed in my applicationHost.xdt